# layer-list: move shape line at the bottom with padding

Tags: android, layer-list

I'm defining a selector background for an edit text and I would like to have a bottom line when the edit text is focused.

This is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

So far I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@android:color/black" />
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="line">
        <stroke android:color="@android:color/black" android:width="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

which shows the line exactly in the middle, and I would like to have it at the bottom, with also a left and right padding.

Is there a way to achieve that using layer-list, or maybe is there a better approach?

Comment: I would rather use two LinearLayout, one inside another. The container having a border and the desired rectangle form, and the child having 0 height at the bottom part of it's parent. I cannot show an example because  I don't have an Android Studio here, sadly.

Comment: you can create this using layer list please check  answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
       <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
  <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
  <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
  <corners
      android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
      android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
      android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
    </item>
<item android:top="20dp" android:right="5dp" android:left="5dp" >
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#ababb2" />
        </shape>
    </item>
  </layer-list>
```

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't add the left and right padding

Comment: @Manza check now you have the same selector background you wanted.

Comment: This seems to do what I wanted to achieve. But it looks kind black magic to me :) May I ask for a small explaination?

Comment: code itself is self explanatory. two items in layer list one with rectangle shape and one with line shape for corners i have added radius for rectangle and line is having padding for both side as well as for top.